# Displaying image from firebase in react native (hitting error)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

On one screen I'm taking an image and it's uploading to firebase but on another page when I'm trying to donwload the image to display it i'm hitting an error but the error it goes to something random. If I copy and paste the url into the `image src` it works.

I can also console log details from the image but for some reason hitting an error displaying it.

```
export default function DisplayPage() {
    const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('images');
    const sampleImage = imageRef.getDownloadURL();
return (
     <View>
        <Image source={{ uri: sampleImage }} style={{ width: 350, height: 350 }} />
     </View>
  );
}
```

I'm uploding the file in another page

```
 const ref = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref()
        .child('images')
    }
```

I want to just have a page that displays all of the images in the file that I'm in but I can't even get one image to show up.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**
The code error that I get it,  it just refers to some random file within expo and prevents the app from booting (hence the reason why I didn't post it) but the response below actually answered my question. The only thing I'm wondering is *how would you display an entire folder instead of just one image.* Would that go inside of the `child()`? I have tried it both in `child()` and `ref()` and failed at both.

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrapped `getDownloadURL` method in async because it would take time to get an image from it and the view would be `render` initially on page load so it wouldn't render the image until it gets from `getDownloadURL`. So, I have used state for it which renders view again when state reset the image, and this time it loads the image successfully.

```
export default function DisplayPage() {

    const [sampleImage, setSampleImage] = useState(); // set state here

    const getSampleImage = async () => {
       const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('images');
       const url = await imageRef.getDownloadURL().catch((error) => { throw error });
       setSampleImage(url);
    }

   // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
   useEffect(() => {
    getSampleImage();
   });

   return (
     <View>
        {sampleImage ? <Image source={{ uri: sampleImage }} style={{ width: 350, height: 350 }} /> : null }
     </View>
   );
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you! one small question, if I wanted to load all images from a folder how would it be different? Would that go in `child('./'FolderName')'?

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by adding a sentence of explanation.